# Content scripts of a Chrome extension not added

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have this very simple manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Sample Name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "This is a sample description",
    "short_name": "Short Sample Name",
    "permissions": ["tabs", "https://google.com/*", "activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": ["https://www.google.com/*"],
        "js": [
                "background.js",
                "test.js"
            ],
        "css": ["test.css"]
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "This is a sample title",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "icons/icon16.png",
            "32": "icons/icon32.png"
        }
    }
}
```

When I go to url https://www.google.com/ and open the *content scripts* tab in Chrome's dev's tools, I do not see my *test.js* and *test.css* scripts there. And, of course, they're not working in the page.
What should I do to add them and make them work?

P.S. Of course, I've created other files, such as window.html, popup.html, background.js, and test.js and test.css too.
The extension was installed successfully, for I see it in the list of my extensions...

Comment: You probably use `Opera` browser which protects the default search engine. There's an option to allow it.

Comment: Hm, but I use Google Chrome browser, last version,  94.0.4606.81. Thx, I have forgot to mention it.

Comment: 1) Remove `background.js` from content_scripts, it shouldn't be placed there. 2) Open `chrome://policy` and click `show more` for ExtensionSettings if it's there, then look for `runtime_blocked_hosts`. 3) If still nothing, you probably didn't reload the extension on chrome://extensions page after editing it.

Comment: This is the answer! And really, I deleted this script from array and then reloaded the extension. Now all works properly. Thank you.